# Are flight offers price, flight offers search, flight create orders using cache or live results?

Tags: api, amadeus

I am a node js programming, testing the self-service api calls on amadeus website.

I am aware of the whole flow: Flight Offers Search -> Flight Offers Price -> Flight Create Orders. Just curious which api are returning cached results from servers, which return live results.

PS.How does 'create order' actually create flight orders? I do not see url link to book air ticket, like skyscanner's api. All I get is

```
 "type": "flight-order",
    "id": "eJzTd9f39vA0co4AAArzAk8=",
    "associatedRecords": [
      {
        "reference": "KHI2CX",
        "creationDate": "2020-01-09T07:51:00.000",
        "originSystemCode": "GDS",
        "flightOfferId": "1"
      }
    ],
etc...
```

How can a customer book an air ticket from this info?

PPS: Is it possible to skip Flight Offers Price in the flow? If not, how long does response from Flight Offers Price stay valid as input for create orders?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 APIs have live results (no cache), so in theory, if you do a booking right after the search you could skip the price, but as it can take time to browse and select the flight to book it's better to perform the price to make sure the price didn't change and the seat(s) is still available.

Regarding the validity of the Price API: it's valid as long as the price doesn't change and the seat is still available.

Our Flight Create Orders API creates a booking reservation, it doesn't redirect to a website of a travel agency or an airline. You can find more information in our guide: [Create a flight booking engine](https://developers.amadeus.com/get-started/category?id=82&durl=651&parentId=NaN).

Do not hesitate to contact our support team if you want more information.

Comment: Just curious, how does the booking reservation helps a customer to book a ticket through ticket consolidator?

Comment: another relevant question is do you provide cached flight api with a larger quota (or even unlimited) of free query?

Comment: To be able to issue a ticket you need to certified by IATA or ARC. If you are not, you can rely on a consolidator to process the ticketing for you. Once you select a consolidator, we configure the Flight Create Orders API to send the PNR created from the API directly to your consolidator so they can issue the ticket.

Comment: We do not provide this

Comment: Great and concise answer. Thank you.