# Can we store data in local database from flight offers search API for fast performance?

Tags: caching, amadeus

I understood from [Are flight offers price, flight offers search, flight create orders using cache or live results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660772/are-flight-offers-price-flight-offers-search-flight-create-orders-using-cache), all 3 APIs have live results and no-cache.

Can we simply store/cache the data returned from "flight offers search API" to our local database temporarily for faster performance (i.e. to display the data on UI quickly enough instead of going to the API all the time), maybe say for few hours or less?

Is it allowed or not? or is there any better solution to achieve the caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific API you have the right to cache the result to optimize the performances of your application (as long as you do not resell the data you cached).

Keep in mind that the price and availability of flights change a lot, you will have to revalidate your cache or re-price your flight offers regularly.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony, No, I am not here to sell any data or anything like that. What is the best way to re-validate/re-price the flight offer, is it by calling "Flight Offers Price" or Is there any API where we will send a list of Flight/Segment Id and get details of only those selected records. What I meant is if I would like to know details of 10 specific flights/segments, Can I get the information related to those 10 flights/segments whose id we passed to API?

Comment: You are right: Flight Offers Price will do exactly this: for a selected list of flight offers it will revalidate the price and the availability. You cannot pass the id directly you need to pass the list of flight offers with all information (all the JSON, please take a look at the reference documentation on the portal). I am about to publish a technical blog article explaining in detail how the Flight Search / Price / Book work.